# How can I stop my script from going back to the top of the page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm testing some Jquery Ajax scripts and one of them is actually quite nice. The only problem I have with it, is that when it refreshes my div, it takes you back to the top of the div.

The div loads MYSQL results from an outside php script. So if the user is halfway down the page reading, when the ajax call goes out, it takes them to the top of the div.

It's important for them to be able to read uninterrupted.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#test').fadeOut("slow").load('tehloader2.php?load=tester').fadeIn("slow");
}, 20000);
</script>

<br /><br />
<div id="test"></div>
```

So would it be possible to have just a stack effect by modifying the code, or would I need to look at a completely different option?

Also I would like to note that after so long, this script starts to fail. It gets to the point where it's constantly refreshing the div. No 20 second wait, just again and again.

Comment: Have you tried just loading it without fading it out and then in?

Comment: This my help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209861/setting-html-page-vertical-position-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should stop it from going to the top:

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#test').load('tehloader2.php?load=tester');
}, 20000);
</script>

<br /><br />
<div id="test"></div>
```

This will make it just load instead of fading the element out and then back in.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That works great. I believe the fading is the problem, both with the eventual fail, and the way it takes the user back to the top. Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.scrollTop()` and `.scrollLeft()` to save the scroll position before loading your content and then set the scroll position back to those values after loading the content.  If the content has changed significantly above the reading position, it won't necessarily go back to the exact same position, but if the content hasn't changed significantly or if the place that it changed is below what was being viewed, it should restore back to the exact same spot.

A more complicated approach would involve identifying a marker object that's on screen and visible and using jQuery `.offset()` and `position()`, you obtain that objects location on screen and then after loading the new content, you adjust the scroll position until that marker object is again positioned in the same place.  This approach is a lot more work, but would give better results if the content changes significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The effect occur because when the content is loaded the div probably is recreated, and that makes the browser go to the top of the `div`. 
You can save the scroll position and try to restore it after.

But depending on what you're doing, if you're loading new content probably it will be helpfull to load the content into another hidden `div` and then append the new content to the visible `div` using the effects u want.

Hope it helps.